# How to check PC monitor is turned on or off any tool or event viewer in windows 7

Tags: windows

I need to check my pc monitor is turned on or off in win7 os

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN power management documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explains that you can get notifications when the monitor is turned on or off.  Basically, you register for the power broadcast messages, and then you'll get a [`WM_POWERBROADCAST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message whenever there's a change.  There are several different GUIDs for monitoring the display state, depending on which version of Windows you use.

At the beginning of your program (after creating your main windows), you do something like:

```
HPOWERNOTIFY hPower =
  RegisterPowerSettingNotification(hwndMain, GUID_SESSION_DISPLAY_STATUS, 0);
```

(There are other [choices for the GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) depending on which version of Windows you're targeting.)

Then in your main window procedure:

```
case WM_POWERBROADCAST:
  if (wParam == PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE) {
    const POWERBROADCAST_SETTING *pSetting =
      reinterpret_cast<const POWERBROADCAST_SETTING*>(lParam);
    if (pSetting->PowerSetting == GUID_SESSION_DISPLAY_STATUS) {
      assert(pSetting->DataLength >= sizeof(DWORD));
      DWORD data = *reinterpret_cast<const DWORD*>(&pSetting->Data);
      switch (data) {
        case 0: /* monitor is off */ break;
        case 1: /* monitor is on */ break;
        case 2: /* monitor is dimmed */ break;
        default:  /* ???? */ break;
      }
    }
  }
  break;
```

If at any point you no longer care about the power notifications, you can unregister:

```
UnregsisterPowerSettingNotification(hPower);
hPower = NULL;
```

Comment: I did it like this and I still dont get any power message. What can be the problem. I have multiple OpenGL windows distributed on differrent monitors, tried this methods but no result ....

Comment: Double-check the documentation that I linked to.  It looks like it's been updated to say GUID_SESSION_DISPLAY_STATUS works in Windows 8 or Server 2012 (and up), but not in earlier versions of the OS.

Comment: For older OSes, there's GUID_MONITOR_POWER_ON, but that only tells you about the primary monitor.

Comment: This only works if I dont turn of the monitor by myself. Practically it seems there is no method to see if the user turns it of, by hand

Comment: Tried it, works like a champ!! exactly what I needed!! OS: Windows 8.1